# Running an application that requires read access to /proc

Tags: permissions, proc

I'm trying to run an [application](https://github.com/vrutkovs/dogtail/blob/master/scripts/dogtail-run-headless-next) that requires access to /proc in order to find the gnome-shell process and its environment variables. My guess is that this application used to work but default security policies have been tightened since. And the only help I was able to find dated 2011 (to [run as user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064859/cannot-automate-a-remote-program-using-python-and-dogtail-no-graphical-interfac), i.e. `sudo -u user app ...`) no longer works. What other other options have I got?

If it matters, the objective is to run the application in a CI environment.

Comment: The application and gnome-shell run as the same user?

Comment: @HaukeLaging No they do not.

Comment: What OS is that?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. What is the output of `grep ' proc ' /proc/mounts`? How is the application started (Systemd service)?